# C# string replacement , not working

Tags: c#, string

I have a string which I read in from :

```
TextReader tr = new StreamReader(this.dataPath );
string contents = tr.ReadToEnd();
```

The value of contents begins with:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n....."
```

When I try execute

```
        string styleSheet = "<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"message.xsl\"?>";
        string xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader(this.dataPath );
        string contents = tr.ReadToEnd(); 
        contents.Replace(xmlString,xmlString + styleSheet );
```

It absolutely won't find the first occurance of XmlString. Any ideas why?

Comment: Very common logic problem in .net. it Got me when I first started as well. But I am glad it works this way.

Comment: Thanks JL for not posting "omg, string.Replace is broken in .net!"

Comment: It would be nice if Replace was a static method instead of an instance method and/or if Visual Studio would give you "return value is not being used" warning.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try

```
contents = contents.Replace(xmlString,xmlString + styleSheet );
```

This is because the String class is immutable.

Comment: I used to do that all of the time.

Comment: @Ed I still do it from time to time :)

Answer (score 5):

The Replace() method returns a new string object, so you'll have to change your code to:

```
 content = contents.Replace(xmlString,xmlString + styleSheet );
```

Answer (score 3):

you probably want to do this:

```
string styleSheet = "<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"message.xsl\"?>";
string xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
TextReader tr = new StreamReader(this.dataPath );
string contents = tr.ReadToEnd(); 
string result = contents.Replace(xmlString,xmlString + styleSheet );
```

You're currently not capturing the replace results that you're doing on the last line.

Answer (score 2):

`System.String` is immutable.  Operations such as `Replace` return a new string rather than modifying `this` string.  Use `System.Text.StringBuilder` if you truly need a mutable string or just assign the result of the `Replace` call to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

To get technical (and who doesn't love that), if you are searching for the string`

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n.....
```

The search string would have to be

```
"<?xml version=\\\"1.0\\\" encoding=\\\"utf-8\\\"?>\\r\\n"
```

or

```
 @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really answer your question but that has already been answered more than once so please permit me this aside.

I've seen many cases where people read the content of a stream into a string so that some really simple manipulation can be done. In many cases and certainly this case the operation can be performed without ever making a copy of the whole string and working on that.

With a little more effort than your existing code you could write a StreamStringReplace method that takes as its parameters an input stream, an output stream, a find string and a replace string. This would be much more efficient especially if your xml docs can get massive.