# Splitting and Trimming to Extract Value

Tags: c#, split, trim

In my program, I read a line which has been sent by the stream, and it is stored in a variable called result.

The result might be "GET /data". and I want to extract "data" from this.

I do a split with spaces, which is stored in an array string so after that I get in the variable parts:
GET
/data

But now I only want to trim "/" infront of data. I tried "trimstart" but hasn't worked. Any Suggestions?

```
string[] delimiters = new string[] { " ", "\r\n"};
string[] lineParts = result.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
result.TrimStart('/');
```

Comment: Strings are immutable, use: `result = result.TrimStart('/');`

Comment: There are lots of similar questions about `Replace()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461383/c-sharp-string-replacement-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Like all string methods, `TrimStart` returns a new string object, it doesn't change the original one. And it can't because strings are [immutable types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) in .NET. You can't change them.

That's why you need to re-assign that returned object to same string or a different one.

```
lineParts[1] = lineParts[1].TrimStart('/');
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/XpXvru)</kbd>.

Comment: I think in this case, I am trying to trim the array lineParts. The index[1] contains "/data", how would I go on about trimming "/" from the array?

Comment: @mca-surround you can do it like; `lineParts[1] = lineParts[1].TrimStart('/');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Split function to extract your data.

```
string[] rslt = result.Split('/');
string data = rslt[1].ToString();
```

This data will contains the extracted data.

See the [demo](http://ideone.com/1Pt3DB)

Answer (score 0):

This will Trim `/` on every string in the lineParts:

```
string result = "GET /DATA";
string[] delimiters = new string[] { " ", "\r\n" };
string[] lineParts = result.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // contains {"GET", "/DATA"}
string[] newLineParts = lineParts.Select(o=>o.TrimStart('/')).ToArray(); // contains {"GET" , "DATA"}
```